# Excel sees date/time value as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I exported some data from a database as an excel file. One column contains date/time values in the following format:

```
2015-04-09 14:05:11.867
```

where the .867 indicate miliseconds. Excel reognizes this column as text. If I remove the miliseconds than excel considers it a date (because it suddenly aligns right instead of left). Changing the format of the field to time or date doesn't help. How can I make excel see the column values as date/times?

Comment: Have you tried a custom format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000`?

Comment: What locale are you in? I just imported the text above and it recognised it fine but my default short date format in Windows is set to ISO: ```yyyy-mm-dd```. The other possibility is that you have leading/trailing whitespace, that will cause that problem.

Comment: My windows default short date format is different but I'd rather not change it for just one stylesheet. I have no white spaces its just this in the field.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that for Dutch regional settings you need a **comma** between the seconds and the milliseconds - that would explain why it's recognised as a date/time when you remove the milliseconds.

Try using `Edit/Replace` on your date/time column to replace all the "**.**"s with "**,**"s [replace dots with commas]

You might have to reformat afterwards as **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss,000**

Note the **comma** in that format

Answer (score 1):

If the value in, say, **A1** is text, then in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,9999))
```

and format **B1** according to your needs:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for helping out. I tried the formula and replaced A1 with the right column but it says the formula has an error which points to the MID() function's first argument (ie. C1). I went to custom format and didn't see: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 so I tried to add it but it says that excel cannot use that format.